# Adding Moq to .netcore project

Tags: moq, .net-core-2.1

I have class library project (Target framework .net core 2.1) and trying to add Moq nuget.

Nuget installed but doesn't seems to be working. Please see below

[image]

Do I need to do something different in here

Comment: *doesn't seem to be working* how? That statement doesn't seem to tell us much. Making the question unclear.

Comment: Had it install as normal nuget and not been able to refer to Mock when check can see this yellow warning icon under Dependencies

Comment: You might be missing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` nuget. Try adding that as well

Comment: You don't need `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` for a test project.

Comment: it was fixed after adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. Thanks